On base $b$ digits of $n\#$ (primorial)
Related to
normal numbers.
Let $n\#$ denote the primorial, the product of the first $n$ primes.

Q1 For all bases $b>1$, do the base $b$ digits of $n\#$ occur
with equal asymptotic frequency $\frac1b$?

Numerical experiments suggest this is true.

"approximately equal" is not very well-defined. What exactly are you asking?

Surely the answer is, of course they do, but proof is hopelessly out of reach.
